# res.send not working for object?

Tags: node.js, express

Here's the code, htis is node.js using the express framework:

---

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Expressxx' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var body = '';

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
     body += chunk;
     });

  req.on('end', function() {
     console.log(body);
     });

  /* res.send('Got the Post'); */

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.send('this is the body' + body);
  res.end();

});

module.exports = router;
```

---

When i do the console.log(body); i see the expected data, but in the client all i see is 'this is the body'. Seems the res.send is not able to read the body obj?

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above sends the response before the `data` event is triggered, so `body` is never built out. Moving the `res.send` and associated calls inside the `end` event handler should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more testing, seems that res.send will send an obj if it is a Json obj...in my case its just plain text in the body obj.

When i read about this method here...
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

It says:
The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array

It didn't say it had to be a json obj???